# How do I test if a Linq to SQL query returns no rows?

Tags: linq-to-sql

How do I test if a Linq to SQL query returns no rows?

Answer (score 8):

The `.Any()` LINQ operator:

```
results.Any()
```

Returns false if there are no rows.

Comment: wish I could mark this as answered for you because I had the exact same question and your response was correct

Answer (score 0):

You can use `results.Any();` (the [Queryable.Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.any.aspx) method).